# Filtering values from a list in a java 8 stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

What we have is a list of objects of type Object, we might take them from a cache for example, so we want to iterate over that list with a lambda stream and after mapping an object in every iteration we want to see if attribute of that new class is present in a list of string values that we passed to the method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not optimised. Using `List.contains` will give you `O(n*m)` complexity. Use a `HashSet` instead:

```java
public List<MyClass> getMyClassListByStates(List<String> states) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(states);
    return cache.getCacheByCacheNameList(CacheTypeConstants.MY_CLASS)
                .stream()
                .map(MyClass.class::cast)
                .filter(myc -> set.contains(myc.getState()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will run in `O(max(n,m))` time instead of `O(n*m)`.

Comment: Note that since Java 16 you can use `.toList()` on the stream directly.

Comment: Yes, but the OP explicitly tagged the questions as `java-8`

Comment: That is fair, then I will just leave the note for any future visitor.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution to that problem:

```
public List<MyClass> getMyClassListByStates(List<String> states) {
    return cache.getCacheByCacheNameList(CacheTypeConstants.MY_CLASS)
            .stream()
            .map((myc) -> (MyClass) myc)
            .filter(myc -> states.contains(myc.getState()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If someone has any other way to do it, please be free to comment, thx.

Comment: If you want someone to criticize your solution it's better to put it in your Question instead of posting it as an Answer

Comment: Your `states.contains` call is expensive. Go `Set` and it will be faster. Personally, I would prefer a method reference on the cast, so `MyClass.class::cast`. Also, with Java 16+ you can just use `.toList()` on the stream directly and do not need `.collect(Collectors.toList())` anymore.